# primefaces accordion, dynamic="true", last panel is empty?

Tags: dynamic, primefaces, accordion

I have a Primefaces 3.4.2 accordion in a WebSphere web app.  It works great when it is not dynamic, but there is a lot of content so I want to make it dynamic.

When I set dynamic="true" the last panel of the accordion is empty with no content, all the other panels are still working normally.  Why is this?

Comment: I just tried the same thing with tabView control, that one works fine when dynamic.  It's only accordion which loses the last panel content when dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded from 3.4.2 to 3.5 and now it is working (I didn't make any code changes).  Looks like it must be a bug in 3.4.2.